# Reload .twig template with AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, twig, timber

I am using https://github.com/gmrchk/swup in combination with Twig/Timber. It works great, however, I have realised that none of my if clauses work whenever I get to a new page, since SWUP can't read the if arguments from my twig files. (it is a JS library to load pages dynamically)

For example:

```
{% if fn('is_single') %}
<div class="progress"></div>
{% endif %}
```

wouldn't load at all when I initially load the page on a not single-post page.

My idea was to re-render header.twig (where the above mentioned if clause is) with an AJAX call.

The AJAX call looks like that:

```
function swupReplaceHeader() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'spx_replace_header',
        },
        success: function (output) {
            console.log(output);
        }
    });
}

swupReplaceHeader();
document.addEventListener('swup:clickLink', swupReplaceHeader);
```

It is wrapped inside an event listener that fires every time I click on a link.

The WP function looks like that:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_spx_replace_header', 'spx_replace_header');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_spx_replace_header', 'spx_replace_header');
function spx_replace_header()
{
    $context = Timber::get_context();
    Timber::render('templates/header.twig', $context);
    wp_send_json_success(['AJAX is working']);
}
```

I added the send JSON message to test if my AJAX call is working.

Now, whenever I test the AJAX call without the Timber code it is working, but when I add the two Timber lines to the function, nothing happens - not even the JSON message appears. I tried Timber::compile as well without any luck.

I hope someone can help me..

Best,
Dennis

Comment: Hi Dennis, This is not really a Timber issue, it seems to stem from a misunderstanding of how AJAX works, and what the responsibilities of the client and the server are.

If you're trying to implement a progress loading bar, then you'd do that client side, outside the swup container so that it persists between requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer posted by aj-adl on [Github](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1993):

> Hey Dennis,
>
> You're making a call to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, so conditionals like is_ajax() will return true but is_single() will definitely not.
>
> Remember that PHP shuts down at the end of each request, discarding state etc, so the call to the admin-ajax.php script is a completely isolated process from the one that's delivered the initial markup for the page, and doesn't know what page it's being called from etc
>
> For this reason, you'd want to pass in any data you'd need for conditionals, probably as a query string parameter.

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_spx_replace_header', 'spx_replace_header');

function spx_safe_get_string( $key )
{
    if ( ! isset( $_GET[ $key ] ) ) return '';
   return sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ $key ] );
}

function spx_replace_header()
{
    $context = Timber::get_context();
    // Set this in the context, so we can access it in our twig file easily
    $context[ 'type' ] = spx_safe_get( 'my_page_type' );
    Timber::render('templates/header.twig', $context);
}
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'spx_replace_header',
            my_page_type: 'single',
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

Twig:

```
{% embed "objects/header.twig" with {'hamburger': 'hamburger--spring'} %}
{% endembed %}

{% if type == 'single' %}
    <div class="progress"></div>
{% endif %}

{% embed "objects/header.twig" with {'id': '--sticky', 'hamburger': 'hamburger--spring'} %}
{% endembed %}
```